# How can I convert hexadecimal fraction to decimal in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, numbers

Is there a way to convert hexadecimal fractions (i.e.: numbers with values <1.0, represented in hex) into their decimal equivalents in PowerShell?

Examples:

```
Hex                  Dec
0.0858b9da24fb4cac = 0.032603851087498366
0.8c3115559ab0c10b = 0.5476239522928976
```

Guides I've found for general HEX/DEC conversion say to use `[Convert]`, which is fine for whole numbers, but it seems to completely fail when I throw a decimal point in the string.

*Note: Examples were taken from data on another site, where these calculations are routinely done. I haven't fully verified their accuracy - there may be some error in the last few digits. Fortunately, I won't be using that much precision anyway.*

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a builtin .Net way to do it. I wrote this brute-force converter, but your values don't seem to exactly match up with .Net type precision - [[double]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) (64bit) is too low precision, and [[decimal]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) (128bit) is more.

Your examples come out like so:

```
0.0858b9da24fb4cac = 0.032603851087498366
                   = 0.0326038510874983682928164128

0.8c3115559ab0c10b = 0.5476239522928976
                   = 0.5476239522928976344718082711
```

Code:

```
<#
.Synopsis
   Converts strings containing hexadecimal numbers with fractional components
   into base-10 [decimal] numbers.

.EXAMPLE

   PS C:\> ConvertFrom-HexFraction '0.0858b9da24fb4cac'
   0.0326038510874983682928164128

.Example

   PS C:\> '0.0858b9da24fb4cac', '0.8c3115559ab0c10b' | ConvertFrom-HexFraction
   0.0326038510874983682928164128
   0.5476239522928976344718082711
#>
function ConvertFrom-HexFraction
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([decimal])]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string]$hexValue
    )

    Process
    {
        # strip leading hex indicator, setup result placeholder of desired type.
        $hexValue = $hexValue -replace '^(0x|&h)'
        $result = [decimal]0

        # Loop over the digits (hexits?) in the string, skip the (hexa)decimal point '.'
        # and calculate (value * base ^ columnNum) for each.

        $i = $hexValue.IndexOf('.') - 1
        [char[]]$hexValue | Where { $_ -ne '.' } | ForEach {

            $result += [convert]::ToInt32($_, 16) * [Math]::Pow(16, $i--)

        }

        $result #output the result
    }

}


ConvertFrom-HexFraction '0.0'
ConvertFrom-HexFraction 'a.a'
ConvertFrom-HexFraction '0.0858b9da24fb4cac'
ConvertFrom-HexFraction '0.8c3115559ab0c10b'
'0.0858b9da24fb4cac', '0.8c3115559ab0c10b' | ConvertFrom-HexFraction
```

Comment: FYI: Added a note about the examples' accuracy to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this one caught my interest. I didn't even know that hexadecimal fractions were a thing, so I went and looked it up. Converting them isn't covered in the `[math]` or `[convert]` libraries that I can see, so we'll have to write up a function that takes care of it for us. I wrote this up, and it's relatively accurate, but you have to consider that a fraction as small as you have it there's going to be some rounding... I mean really, for your first example even you rounded. The last digit alone is something like `6.50521303491303E-19` (which is 12*(16^-16)).

So, that function looks like:

```
Function HexToInt([string]$TextIn){
$Pre,$Post = $TextIn.split('.')

$PostConverted = For($i=1;$i -le $Post.Length;$i++){
    [convert]::ToInt32($Post[($i-1)],16) * [math]::pow(16,($i*-1))
}
$PostSum = $PostConverted | Measure-Object -Sum |% Sum
$Int = [convert]::ToInt64($Pre,16)
$Int+$PostSum
}
```

That should convert your fractions for you.

Comment: *I didn't even know that hexadecimal fractions were a thing* -- This is why in 2016 we still don't have nice library routines to handle this stuff!  I kid but.. you get my point. ;)

Comment: FYI: Added a note about the examples' accuracy to the question.